# Android Moving Bitmap in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an activity with an `imageView` which has a canvas, and under it a button. when I click the button a new bitmap gets drawn into the canvas with text ..
How do I make the drawn bitmap moveable like I drag it into any place I want in the canvas ?

```
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(WorkBitmap);
                    c.drawText("Bitmap", 360, 520, null);
                    c.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, null);
```

I saw some tutorials on `SurfaceView`  and I did them, thye worked fine. But I want the bitmap in my canvas to move, in the tutorials its the whole screen a surfaceView canvas ..

Comment: I think you should redraw the bitmap in canvas if you want to move it. Why don't you just move it's container? (The whole View that you drew the bitmap in its canvas)

Comment: I mean the bitmap is like a sticker, you move it around the canvas using your finger *sorry for late reply*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `SurfaceView` widget that is available in the XML

But if you want the image to be move-able around all the screen you could use `SurfaceView`

[Check this Youtube video, It's very informative (watch all the SurfaceView playlist to benefit)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2YogvILjvo)